# ggplot2: Plotting multiple vectors sequentially

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have two vectors, say

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,1,3)
vec2 <- c(3,3,2,4)
```

I want to plot both vectors in series, in different colors, on GGPlot. For example, to plot a single vector in series, I could simply do:

```
qplot(seq_along(vec1),vec1))
```

But I want to plot both in series, so we can pairwise compare the entries visually. The graph would look something like:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest looking at the ggplot documentation, essentially you just need a plot canvas with multiple stored vectors or if you convert the vectors in to a df you can just pass the df in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to make a data frame from `vec1` and `vec2`. Since `ggplot2` prefers data in long format, we convert `df` to `df_long` using `gather` from the `tidyr` package (after creating `id` column using `mutate` function from the `dplyr` package). After that it's fairly easy to do the plotting.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776963/786542) to learn more about changing the `shape` of the points

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

vec1 <- c(1,2,1,3)
vec2 <- c(3,3,2,4)

df <- data.frame(vec1, vec2)
df_long <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id)
df_long

#>   id  key value
#> 1  1 vec1     1
#> 2  2 vec1     2
#> 3  3 vec1     1
#> 4  4 vec1     3
#> 5  1 vec2     3
#> 6  2 vec2     3
#> 7  3 vec2     2
#> 8  4 vec2     4

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = id, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = key, shape = key), size = 3) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).