# Editing the title of legend in R line chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had previously asked a question about plotting multiple lines in a linechart using ggplot2.

Here: [Adding a second legend to line chart in ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226953/adding-a-second-legend-to-line-chart-in-ggplot2-in-r)

I am using the solution provided there to generate the chart, however I want to modify the title of the legend.

I tried the following:

```
tidyr::gather(m, foo, value, -bar) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(bar, value, colour = foo, linetype = foo)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "my awesome title")
```

and I get the following.

[image]

The above creates a separate legend called "my awesome title". I want a single legend where the title of the legend would be "my awesome title".

I have attempted the various solutions mentioned here: [How to change legend title in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot) but I cannot get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to retain the `foo` legend or just remove the `foo` title?

Comment: Add `+ scale_linetype_discrete("my awesome title")` to your plot or `+
  labs(colour = "my awesome title", linetype = "my awesome title")` instead of `scale_color_discrete`.

Comment: Thanks @markus your solution worked for me!