# Changing Title of Legend in ggplot2 Creates a Second Legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, legend, data-analysis

I am pretty new to R/working with data and am trying to change the title of the legend in a visualization I made. I have tried using `fill=` in the `labels()` function I have but it adds another legend for some reason. I have looked around for a solution and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244129/editing-the-title-of-legend-in-r-line-chart-in-ggplot2) however neither solution solved my problem.

Here is my code as I had it originally along with the visualization it makes:

```
data_2023_2 %>% 
  group_by(rideable_type, member_type) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(total_trips = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rideable_type, y=total_trips, fill=member_type, color=member_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0.1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = total_trips), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = 0.9, padding = 0.1), vjust=1.5, colour="white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkorchid","darkseagreen")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkorchid","darkseagreen")) +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title="Number of Trips by Bike Type", x="Bicycle Type", y="Number of Rides")
```

[image: Viz With Bad Legend Title]

And then here is the code with `fill=` added in

```
data_2023_2 %>% 
  group_by(rideable_type, member_type) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(total_trips = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rideable_type, y=total_trips, fill=member_type, color=member_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0.1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = total_trips), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = 0.9, padding = 0.1), vjust=1.5, colour="white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkorchid","darkseagreen")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkorchid","darkseagreen")) +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title="Number of Trips by Bike Type", x="Bicycle Type", y="Number of Rides", fill="Member Type")
```

[image: Viz With 2 Legends But One of Them Has The Good Title I Want]

Comment: You could try adding `color ="Member Type"` to the `labs()` call.

Comment: I was just about to type the same thing ... note that you have `member_type` and `Member Type`, one over `color=` (boundary) and one over `fill=`, that should be the hint to push you in the right direction. FYI, I tend to use `scale_fill_manual(name="..")` instead of `labs(fill=..)` (and same for `scale_color_manual`), but I don't know that it's for much more than keeping `_fill_`-aesthetic parameters well grouped. For similar reasons, I would define `c("darkorchid",..)` in one vector and reuse it in each of your scales.

Comment: omg thank you all so much! r2evans and jefferyohene were right, the fill and color in my original `aes` function should have been a tipoff!! I think I've been staring at this code for too long today. Thanks for the tip about defining the colors as vectors too, I am going to use that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that in the labs function like this:

```
data_2023_2 %>% 
  group_by(rideable_type, member_type) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(total_trips = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rideable_type, y=total_trips, fill=member_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0.1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = total_trips, fill = member_type), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = 0.9, padding = 0.1), vjust=1.5, colour="white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkorchid","darkseagreen")) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title="Number of Trips by Bike Type", x="Bicycle Type", y="Number of Rides", fill="Member Type")
```

Comment: worked perfect, thank you so much! I think I've been staring at this project for too long today lol